# How to run an old Windows 95 CD ROM (Monty Python game) on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: virtualbox, windows, wine, games

I'm trying to find out how to run the Monty Pythons Game (Sacré Graal) (Windows 95 CD ROM) on Ubuntu (18.10).

I tried with VirtualBox but I can't find a Windows 95 image and it takes a long time to set up. Is there any emulator or other tool I can use to run this CD ROM?

I already tried to use wine but it didn't work. Can we select Windows 95 with Wine?

Dear

Comment: This isn't really about Ubuntu, other than this is where you happen to want to run VirtualBox or Wine. This is also pretty broad. My advice is create a Win95 VM (you can find install ISOs all over the place if you search) and configure it to grab the CDROM player (or figure out how to mount it as an ISO). Or configure Wine to emulate Win95 and try to install it that way. Related https://superuser.com/q/398178/609232

Comment: I am not sure whether this is your game, but other Monty Python game is just working fine with wine. For programs running with wine you do not need Windows 95 CD. Even DOSBOX is supporting some Win 95 executables.

Comment: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=2178

Comment: @jdv Questions about running software on Ubuntu are about Ubuntu. So just to be clear, this question is on-topic.

Comment: If you try running it with wine in a terminal and [edit] your question to show the output, being able to look at the errors instead of just hearing 'it didn't work' would be helpful.